# Query params for filtration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my REST application I have got GET method that handles requests with pagination params (offset and limit). And also it handles filter and sorting params, e.g. I can set filter like that 'id eq 5' and sorting like 'name desc'. But parameter for filter it's just query string parameter and for create request with 2 filters, e.g. 'id eq 5, size gt 10'. Can I handle request with 2 filter parameters as 2 independent query params? And yes, I can just add 2 `@RequestParam` for 2 independent params in my method. But what if there is possibility to filter request by 10-15 parameters ? Does it mean that I should set 10-15 params in method with `@RequestParam(required = false)` or there is more convenient way to handle it?

In summary, I would like to have got something like with `host/filterkey1[operator]=value1&filterkey2[operator]=value2` and right now I have got this: `host/filter=filterkey1[operator]value1,%filterkey2[operator]value2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate a map with `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestParam Map<String, String> filters
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

> If the method parameter is Map or MultiValueMap and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. I also found something like your suggestion. There is possibility to add `HttpServletRequest` to method's list parameters and take all filter params with excluding sort, limit and offset :) Thank you so much!